# Filling in proof in UC Davis notes

Tags: real-analysis, proof-writing

I am working through the UC Davis [analysis notes](https://www.math.ucdavis.edu/~hunter/pdes/ch3A.pdf), and was referred to the appendix for the theorem 3.62, which is not proven:

> If $f, g:[a, b] \to \mathbb{R}$ are absolutely continuous, then 
>   $$
> \int_a^b fg'dx = f(b)g(b) - f(a)g(a) - \int_a^bf'gdx
> $$
>   where $f', g'$ denote the pointwise a.e. derivatives of $f, g$.

I wanted to prove it myself, so I first showed that $fg$ is absolutely continuous. This part I am confident in. But then I was not sure how to go past that without using the FTC for Lebesgue Integrals, which I have not been exposed to yet in my study so I don't think I should use it.

How can I prove this result from first principles without using FTC for Lebesgue Integrals, after proving that $fg$ is absolutely continuous?

I tried researching online and found proofs like [this one](https://sites.ualberta.ca/~rjia/Math418/Hwks/sol4.pdf) online, but they just say

> ...$fg$ is absolutely continous, and furthermore we have
>   $$
> f(b)g(b) - f(a)g(a) = \int_a^b(fg)'dx = \int_a^b[fg' + f'g]dx
> $$

which isn't really a justification to me. How does this Chain Rule actually follow?

Comment: Unless you want to go through the analysis of showing absolutely continuous function have the FTC property, I don't see any easier way. I think in the notes they did prove FTC and used it to justify the assertion.

Comment: @JackyChong So there is no straightforward way to show that $(fg)' = f'g + fg'$ a.e.? Because from there it looks clear.

Comment: That's just product rule.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to prove this statement without essentially using or reproving the FTC for Lebesgue integrals of absolutely continuous functions.  Indeed, notice that if you set $f=1$, you get exactly the FTC for $g$, so the FTC follows immediately from this result.